# How to install chromium in Docker based on Ubuntu 19.10 and 20.04?

Tags: docker, ubuntu, chromium

I have this simple docker file:

```
FROM ubuntu:eoan 

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive 

RUN apt update && apt install -y \ 
  chromium-browser \ 
  chromium-chromedriver
```

When I try to build it:

```
...
Preparing to unpack .../00-chromium-browser_77.0.3865.120-0ubuntu1.19.10.1_amd64.deb ...
=> Installing the chromium snap
==> Checking connectivity with the snap store
===> Unable to contact the store, trying every minute for the next 30 minutes
```

And it seems that it never reaches the said snap store.
It works fine if the image is based on `disco` instead of `eoan`.
It works fine on a physical machine.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It's not a solution, it's a workaround. Just use `google-chrome` instead. 
I faced with this issue when suddenly in one day that docker image that always was building become broken. My case was like your: ubuntu 19.10 as a base for docker image.

```sh
RUN curl -LO https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
RUN apt-get install -y ./google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
RUN rm google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

Comment: Tip: Even though less readable making the three RUN stanzas one and chain them with `&&` causes the resulting image layers to be smaller. If `rm` is in a separate `RUN` the data will consume the place in the layer for the first `RUN`.

Comment: That's what we are doing as well.

Comment: Sadly this does not work with ARM chips such as the Raspberry Pi. Any Ideas?

Comment: using `apt-get install chromium` worked in my docker build. there's also this beta option that i was about to try: https://fosspost.org/chromium-deb-package-ubuntu-20-04/

Comment: @JörgRech for ARM (Raspberry Pi) it is useful to use these binaries (.deb) https://launchpad.net/~canonical-chromium-builds/+archive/ubuntu/stage/+build/20359945

Comment: for me this does not work as it has many unmet dependencies:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
`Depends: fonts-liberation but it is not installable
Depends: libasound2 (>= 1.0.16) but it is not installable
Depends: libatk-bridge2.0-0 (>= 2.5.3) but it is not installable
Depends: libatspi2.0-0 (>= 2.9.90) but it is not installable
Depends: libdrm2 (>= 2.4.38) but it is not installable
Depends: libgbm1 (>= 8.1~0) but it is not installable
Depends: libgtk-3-0 (>= 3.9.10) but it is not installable
Depends: libnspr4 (>= 2:4.9-2~) but it is not installable...`

Comment: @stevenhurwitt it works your answer for me. thanks